# How to use setBalance method in my entity to set the actual balance value of a member?

Tags: android, android-room

I use Android Room for my database. I have a title screen and when I click on a button there, my activity opens. The activity shows me a list of members saved in the database. My entity Member consists of first name, surname and balance. I can add new members. The user can set first name and surname, the balance is automatically set with the value 0. I do have another entity called transactions, where I can add transaction and link transactions with members.

If I add two new transactions for a member a, the member a's balance goes up. I can click on a member in my member activity, then I see additional information of the member. There, I can see the actual balance he has with a SUM() query in my DAO.

But I don't know, how to use that query to set Balance of a member. I also don't know where(in which class) I should use the set Balance method of the member class.

Entity Member:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
@Entity(tableName = "member_table")
public class Member {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "MemberID")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Surname")
    private String surname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "MemberBalance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Member(String firstname, String surname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.balance = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

}
```

Entity Transaction:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
@Entity(tableName = "transaction_table")
public class Transaction {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionID")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionName")
    private String transactionName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionBalance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTransactionName() {
        return transactionName;
    }

    public void setTransactionName(String transactionName) {
        this.transactionName = transactionName;
    }

    public Transaction(String transactionName, BigDecimal balance) {
        this.transactionName = transactionName;
        this.balance = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(balance)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }
}
```

[image: This is my member activity where I see the list of all members. The balance is always 0.00 because I never use setBalance() method, and the balance should be the value gotten by the getBalance() method.]

[image: This is my transaction activity where I can see the list of all transactions.]

[image: This activity starts when I click on a member. Then I see the member names and below all the transactions he took part. The balance of the member here is taken with a DAO-Query: SELECT SUM(TransactionBalance)FROM member_transaction_table INNER JOIN transaction_table ON transaction_table.TransactionID = member_transaction_table.Transaction_ID WHERE member_transaction_table.Member_ID =:memberid]

First picture: This is my member activity where I see the list of all members. The balance is always 0.00 because I never use setBalance() method, and the balance should be the value gotten by the getBalance() method.

Second picture: This is my transaction activity where I can see the list of all transactions.

Third picture: This activity starts when I click on a member. Then I see the member names and below all the transactions he took part. The balance of the member here is taken with a DAO-Query: SELECT SUM(TransactionBalance)FROM member_transaction_table INNER JOIN transaction_table ON transaction_table.TransactionID = member_transaction_table.Transaction_ID WHERE member_transaction_table.Member_ID =:memberid

I can't figure out how and where to let the app calculate the transactions. The value returned by the calculations should be set with the setBalance() method.

Can anybody help me with this? If you need any specific code, just write in the comments and I'll add it to this question. Thanks!

Transaction Repository:

```
public class TransactionRepository {

    private TransactionDao mTransactionDao;
    private MemberTransactionDao mMemberTransactionDao;
    private LiveData<List<Transaction>> mAllTransaction;
    private MemberDao mMemberDao;

    TransactionRepository(Application application) {
        SmartBookkeepingRoomDatabase db = SmartBookkeepingRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mTransactionDao = db.transactionDao();
        mMemberTransactionDao = db.memberTransactionDao();
        mMemberDao = db.memberDao();
        mAllTransaction = mTransactionDao.getAllTransactions();
    }

    public void addTransactionBalanceToMember(Member member, Transaction transaction, OnTransactionInsertedListener listener) {
        insert(transaction, listener);
        BigDecimal newBalance = member.getBalance().add(transaction.getBalance());
        member.setBalance(newBalance);
        mMemberDao.update(member);
    }

    LiveData<List<Transaction>> getAllTransactions() {
        return mAllTransaction;
    }


    public void insert(Transaction transaction, OnTransactionInsertedListener listener) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mTransactionDao, listener).execute(transaction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with SUM() method of SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably update the balance when inserting a new transaction in the `transaction_table` table. You can use `@Transaction` to execute 2 queries in a single transaction in your DAO. Something like this should work:

```
@Dao
public abstract class TransactionDao {

    // ...

    @Transaction
    public void insertTransactionForMember(Member member, Transaction transaction) {
        insertTransaction(transaction);
        BigDecimal newBalance = member.getBalance() + transaction.getBalance()
        member.setBalance(newBalance);
        updateMember(member); // implement it here or 
    }

}
```

Now this answer is not ideal. TransactionDao should not contain a method to update member. You should have a repository handle this, call 2 insert methods on 2 DAOs inside a transaction. Also, I don't see a foreign key from Transaction to Member. Adding one might be a good idea

Comment: I do have a class MemberTransaction with the foreign keys. I also do have a Member repository and a Transaction repository. But what do I have to do?

Comment: I have an insert method to insert a member and a insert method to insert a transaction. But what exactly do I have to insert?

Comment: Yes, but how do I do it? Do I need a new AsyncTask? I understand the idea behind your solution, I just can't figure out how to split them and put them in the repositories. Can you help me?

Comment: You don't put them in different repositories. Call the `database.transactionDao().insertTransaction(...)` and `database.memberDao().updateMember(...)` in your repository method to add a transaction.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try it right now and will comment my results.

Comment: Do I have to implement your code into the Repository(Application application) or in the Repository class? I wrote your code into my Repository class and not in the Application. I updated my post with the code to show you how my repository looks like.

Comment: if I try to put the method into the Application, it's missing the parameters, so is this correct the way I have it?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that your DAO is a abstract class and not an interface. Do I have to create a new class with this code to do this? Because I can't change my interface to abstract, the queries won't work.

Comment: I solved the interface - abstract problem. Can you explain how you mean that with the repository?

Comment: please can you help?