# Room: How to use @Transaction in DAO Interface

Tags: android, android-room

Regarding this question's answer: [How to use setBalance method in my entity to set the actual balance value of a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450576/how-to-use-setbalance-method-in-my-entity-to-set-the-actual-balance-value-of-a-m)

The answer suggests to use a @Transaction method. I don't understand how to use this method. Also, my DAO is an interface, the answer's DAO is a abstract.

How do I implement the method suggested in the answers into my interface DAO and then in the repository?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting `@Transaction` on the method in the DAO?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, it gives me this error: Interface abstract method cannot have body.

Comment: add `abstract` in the method. Ex. `abstract long insert(Transactions transaction);`

Comment: @Enzokie Ah, I see, I updated my post with another picture after adding abstract to it. Do the other queries work like they did when the DAO was an interface?

Comment: Yeah it will. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transaction methods in room are methods marked with `@Transaction` annotation.

Since you can not have non-abstract methods in interfaces, you need to use an **abstract class** instead of **interface** for DAO.

For example,

```
@android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
public abstract class AppDao {
    @Transaction
     public void insertAndDeleteInTransaction(Product newProduct, Product oldProduct) {
         // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
         insert(newProduct);
         delete(oldProduct);
     }
}
```

Comment: I have just a small question - Now I have the method, but my @Transaction method uses two different DAOs. The answer in my other question says I should let it handle in the repository. How should I do that? Yes, I will mark it as accepted after it works.

Comment: @LordGash how did you solve your problem with two different DAOs and @Transation?

Comment: I used AsyncTask and it worked. Transaction didn‘t work for me.